# how to pass a list through adb tap & text (in python)

Tags: python, android, list, adb

the command for adb tap and text is

```
device.shell('input tap xcoord ycoord')
```

and

```
device.shell('input text sampletext')
```

but I want to pass a list through them in a for loop such as

```
for users in usernames
usernames = ['abc', 'adnc', 'ajdi'] #list of usernames
device.shell('input text {usernames}')#type username
```

but it will not recognize the list or I get an error such as

```
handler(conn)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

any insight?

Comment: First define the `usernames` array, then start the for loop: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: First command is `tap` but then you use `text`. What do you really want? Why a list of names?